# Разное отображение шрифта в iOS

Tags: wordpress, ios, google-chrome, шрифты, google-fonts

На iOS в хроме один и тот же шрифт может отображаться по разному, особенно жирность.
Пример:
[image: screen]
Шрифт подключал через гугл фонтс:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,400,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
```

Но при подключении вручную тоже бывали подобные прецеденты, в частности с MyriadPro.
Сайт сделан на Wordpress.
Проверял на нескольких макбуках, проблема встречается редко, но встречается.
На виндовс 7 данных "скачков" жирности не замечал.
Обычно жирность скачет в списках.

```css
p{
    font-family: 'Merriweather'!important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    color: #5c5c5c!important;
    line-height: normal!important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    --mobileText: 3vw;
    --mobileLine: 3vw;
    --tabletText: 2vw;
    --tabletLine: 2.5vw;
    --smallText: 2vw;
    --smallLine: 2.5vw;
    --mediumText: 2vw;
    --mediumLine: 2.5vw;
    --largeText: 2vw;
    --largeLine: 2.5vw;
}



li{
 list-style: none!important;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather'!important;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    color: #5c5c5c!important;
    line-height: normal!important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    --mobileText: 3vw;
    --mobileLine: 3vw;
    --tabletText: 2vw;
    --tabletLine: 2.5vw;
    --smallText: 2vw;
    --smallLine: 2.5vw;
    --mediumText: 2vw;
    --mediumLine: 2.5vw;
    --largeText: 2vw;
    --largeLine: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Задание:</strong></p>
<p>Пропишите 3 цели, которые помогут Вам вернуться в те ощущения, которые Вы испытывали выполняя задание на странице первого инсайта.</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 24px!important;"><strong>Напишите в комментариях:</strong></p>
<ul class="list-def"><li>Совпадает ли Ваше целеполагание с тем возрастным периодом, в котором Вы находитесь?</li>
 <li>Совпадает ли Ваше целеполагание с тем возрастным периодом, в котором Вы находитесь?</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а Вы не могли бы приложить разметку указанного на изображении фрагмента и css-стили, которые к нему приложены. Также напишите в вопросе, на какие именно элементы стоит обратить внимание

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Надеюсь, этого будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, в вопросе я сам же на него и дал ответ.
Оказалось что в стилях темы сайта для всех тэгов, кроме `<p>` было прописано свойство `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` а для `<p>` `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` после уравнивания этих значений проблема вроде как решилась.